# knitr called from RStudio does not preserve the order in which packages are loaded

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio, dplyr

When I render Rmd markdown files that used cached chunks in RStudio using the Knit HTML button, I find that the order in which packages are loaded is not remembered from chunk to chunk. This causes problems when I need to load packages in a specific order to avoid namespace clashes.

For a reproducible example (which requires the plyr, dplyr, and pryr packages to be installed, see below), I start by creating a knitr Rmd document that loads plyr and then dplyr (which both export a `summarise` function), then uses [pryr](https://github.com/hadley/pryr) to determine which summarise function is found. I knit this using RStudio's "Knit HTML" button:

````
```{r}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(cache = TRUE, message = FALSE)
```

```{r test1}
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
```

```{r test2, dependson = "test1"}
attr(pryr::where("summarise"), "name")
```
````

As recommended [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr#plyr-compatibility), I load plyr before dplyr so that dplyr's functions should come first in the search path. As expected, the output md file shows that the `summarise` function comes from dplyr:

```
attr(pryr::where("summarise"), "name")
## [1] "package:dplyr"
```

*However*, if I make some small change in the `test2` chunk:

````
```{r test2, dependson = "test1"}
attr(pryr::where("summarise"), "name")  # this is a change
```
````

that causes it to be recompiled, it now loads the packages in the wrong order, and `summarise` is found in plyr:

```
attr(pryr::where("summarise"), "name")  # this is a change
## [1] "package:plyr"
```

Note that this problem does not occur if one is running `knit` from the R command line, but that is only because it keeps the `plyr` and `dplyr` packages loaded in the environment (if I restart R the same problem occurs).

I am aware that I can refer to functions as `dplyr::summarise` to avoid redundancy, but this is rather cumbersome. Not loading `plyr` at all is not an option since several packages inadvertently add it to the namespace. How can I ensure the packages load in the desired order?

I am using the latest version of RStudio (0.98.1079), and my sessionInfo is below:

```
## R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
## Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0 (64-bit)
## 
## locale:
## [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
## 
## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
## 
## other attached packages:
## [1] plyr_1.8.1    dplyr_0.3.0.2 knitr_1.7    
## 
## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
##  [1] assertthat_0.1   codetools_0.2-8  DBI_0.3.0        digest_0.6.4    
##  [5] evaluate_0.5.5   formatR_1.0      htmltools_0.2.4  magrittr_1.0.0  
##  [9] parallel_3.1.1   pryr_0.1.0.9000  Rcpp_0.11.2      rmarkdown_0.3.10
## [13] rstudioapi_0.1   stringr_0.6.2    tools_3.1.1
```

Note that if necessary, you can set up the necessary packages for this reproducible example with:

````
```{r}
install.packages(c("devtools", "plyr", "dplyr"))
devtools::install_github("hadley/pryr")
```
````

Comment: Does this also happen when you use `cache=FALSE`?

Comment: @Andrie: No (and I wouldn't have expected it to), though caching is necessary for my purposes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[My pull request](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/pull/869) to knitr addresses this issue by preserving the order of the search path in the `__packages` file. The relevant code is:

```
x = rev(.packages())
if (file.exists(path)) 
    x = setdiff(c(readLines(path), x), .base.pkgs)
writeLines(x, path)
```

@Yihui merged the request as of [this commit](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/86b8b2d231c6a42f718822ae799e87720f53a126), and it will likely be available in knitr [v1.8](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/milestones/v1.8) in CRAN (or immediately from GitHub or RForge).

There still may be issues when packages are loaded in different chunks that do not depend on each other, but this does fix the example in the question above and in other applications I've tried.

Answer (score 3):

Posting this as an answer since it seems more substantial than a comment.

**tl;dr**: try removing `cache/__packages` manually between runs (and adding `cache=FALSE` to your package-loading chunk/doing without package caching) and see if that solves the problem ... or even add

```
if (file.exists("cache/__packages")) unlink("cache/__packages")
```

(I haven't actually tested this on your example.)

I've had a *lot* of trouble with package caching, especially in working directories where I'm running lots of examples with not-necessarily-compatible package sets. I often just remove `cache/__packages` by hand.  I imagine the design could be improved (but I haven't bothered to construct examples/think about how the design would be improved).

Comment: Loading packages has side effects, and side effects are generally dangerous for caching. The simple solution, as explained at http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/, is _not_ to cache code chunks that have side effects. If anyone knows how to improve the current design, or wants to work on it, please feel free to submit pull requests.

Comment: @Yihui: Thanks- I've submitted [such a request](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/pull/867). I've confirmed it solves the problem in my reproducible example, and unless there's a specific reason for storing packages in alphabetical order I don't think it could cause any problems.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Much appreciated! I'll take a look later.